# Why does a constructor when explicitly called return a temporary object, when it has no return type?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I am learning OOP in C++ and got to know that we can **explicitly** call the constructor as shown below:

```
var obj = var(); // Assume var is a class and obj is an instance of an object of the class var.
```

From what I have understood till now, **var()** constructor instantiates a temporary object, initializes it and then it is sent so that object **obj** copies the contents of it.

Now I have 2 doubts:

1. Is this understanding correct (i.e. does it happen in the way I thought it would)?
2. Also I got to know that a constructor doesn't instantiate an object but **only** initializes the object. If this is true then, why will an object form on the RHS of the above line of code? If no object forms on the RHS, whose contents will get copied to the object **obj**?

Comment: A constructor does not return a temporary object.   It is used to initialise the state of an object.   In `var obj = var()`,  the `var()` constructs an object using the default constructor.   That object is not *returned* by the constructor.

Comment: It's not the responsibility of the constructor to create the object, only to *initialize* it. In short, constructors are always called on already created objects.

Comment: You can't explicitly call constructors – they have no name and can't be referred to. It's just that the object creation syntax looks exactly like the constructor prototype syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax for creating an object looks like the syntax calling a function, but they are different. You can't call a constructor.

In C++17 there isn't even two objects. The temporary value `var()` is materialised as `obj`.

Comment: Yes, this indeed seems to be the case. I have put a copy constructor to see if "copying" is happening and it did not get invoked - essentially implying what you have said.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at the following code disassemble here:

https://godbolt.org/z/aP9eG3

```
class Hello {
public:
    Hello(int x) {this->x = x;}
int x;
};

int main() {
    Hello x = Hello(1);
    Hello y(2);

    x = y;
    return x.x;
}
```

The line `Hello x = Hello(1);` is translated into this:

```
    lea     rax, [rbp-4]
    mov     esi, 1
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    Hello::Hello(int)
```

Explanation line by line:

Line 1. Allocate 4 bytes on the stack

Line 2: Move 1 to be the first function call parameter

Line 3: Pass the address of the new object as an argument

Line 4. Call function Hello::Hello(int)

That's it there is no copy. Memory allocated, object constructed in place.

Line `Hello y(2);` translates into the same thing.

Last, line `x = y;` translates into:

```
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
```

Which is actual memory copy. I think this example illustrates the way C++ actually works, much better than any theoretical explanation.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, by creating an instance of your class `var`, the object is created by calling the constructor. So if you write `var obj;` the creator is called.

The expression `var()` is already called when creating the object. But as nothing is specified, it is not necessary to specify it. It is more interesting to specify the type of constructor you want to use when this one is particular like for example :

```
var obj = var(foo);
```

or

```
var obj(foo);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's perfectly valid to specify which constructor to call by doing `var obj = var();`.

Comment: It is valid but already called... It is easier to read if the constructor is specified only for 'special' constructor for example if you have several consturctors like var()

Comment: That's not what your answer says... *The expression var() is not correct here; the computer is searching a function named var() but doesn't have any clue to understand that is in the class var.* <--- Right here.